# How to implement scoped_lock functionality in c++11 using lock_guard

Tags: c++, c++11

Looks like [scoped_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock/scoped_lock) in c++17 gives the functionality I'm after however I'm presently tied to c++11.

At the moment I'm seeing deadlock issues with guard_lock when we call it with the same mutex more than once. Does scoped_lock protect against multiple calls (i.e. reenterent?)?
Is there a best practice for doing this in c++11 w/ lock_guard?

```
mutex lockingMutex;

void get(string s)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(lockingMutex);
    if (isPresent(s))
    {
        //....
    }
}

bool isPresent(string s)
{
    bool ret = false;
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(lockingMutex);
    //....
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You mean [std::recursive_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex)?

Comment: @freakish yep that's exactly it. thanks

Comment: If you need recursive mutex there is something wrong in locking logic.

Comment: @Slava you might be right... re-looking at the approach now given this and the answer and example below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be able to lock the same mutex multiple times one needs to use [std::recursive_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex). Recursive mutex is more expensive than a non-recursive one.

Best practise, though, is to design your code in such a way that a thread does not lock the same mutex multiple times. For example, have you public functions lock the mutex first and then invoke the implementation function that expects the mutex to have been locked already. Implementation functions must not call the public API functions that lock the mutex. E.g.:

```
class A {
    std::mutex m_;
    int state_ = 0;

private: // These expect the mutex to have been locked.
    void foo_() {
        ++state_;
    }

    void bar_() {
        this->foo_();
    }

public: // Public functions lock the mutex first.
    void foo() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_);
        this->foo_();
    }

    void bar() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_);
        this->bar_();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Scoped lock does not give the functionality you are looking for.

Scoped lock is just a variardic version of lock guard.  It only exists due to some ABI issues with changing lock guard into a variardic template.

To have reentrant mutexes, you need to use a reentrant mutex.  But this is both more expensive at runtime, and usually indicates a lack of care in your mutex state.  While holding a mutex you should have complete and total understanding of all other synchronization actions you are performing.

Once you have complete understanding of all synchronizations actions you are performing, it is easy to avoid recursively locking.

There are two patterns you can consider here.  First, split public locking API from a private non-locking API.  Second, split synchronization from implementation.

```
private:
  mutex lockingMutex;
  bool isPresent(string s, lock_guard<mutex> const& lock) {
    bool ret = false;
    //....
    return ret;
  }
  void get(string s, lock_guard<mutex> const& lock) {
    if (isPresent(s, lock))
    {
      //....
    }
  }
public:  
  void get(string s) {
    return get( std::move(s), lock_guard<mutex>(lockingMutex) );
  }

  bool isPresent(string s) {
    return isPresent( std::move(s), lock_guard<mutex>(lockingMutex) );
  }
};
```

here I use `lock_guard<mutex>` as "proof we have a lock".

An often better alternative is to write your class as non-thread-safe, then use a wrapper:

```
template<class T>
struct mutex_guarded {
  template<class T0, class...Ts,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<T0>, mutex_guarded>{}, bool> =true
  >
  mutex_guarded(T0&&t0, Ts&&...ts):
    t( std::forward<T0>(t0), std::forward<Ts>(ts)... )
  {}
  mutex_guarded()=default;
  ~mutex_guarded=default;

  template<class F>
  auto read( F&& f ) const {
    auto l = lock();
    return f(t);
  }
  template<class F>
  auto write( F&& f ) {
    auto l = lock();
    return f(t);
  }
private:
  auto lock() { return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m); }
  auto lock() const { return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m); }
  mutable std::mutex m;
  T t;
};
```

now we can use this like this:

```
mutex_guarded<Foo> foo;
foo.write([&](auto&&foo){ foo.get("hello"); } );
```

you can write `mutex_gaurded`, `shared_mutex_guarded`, `not_mutex_guarded` or even `async_guarded` (which returns futures and serializes actions in a worker thread).

So long as the class doesn't leave its own "zone of control" in methods this pattern makes writing mutex-guarded data much easier, and lets you compose related mutex guarded data into one bundle without having to rewrite them.

Comment: You probably want `lock_guard<mutex>&&` arguments without the name.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin No, `const&`.  And name is important; it lets you pass it on to other methods in turn.